# proving increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, functions

Given $c>0$. Let $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ be a function defined by
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}x}\int_{-c}^ct^2e^{-\frac{t^2}{2x^2}}dt.
\end{equation}
I'd like to prove that $f$ is increasing. I am sure about that because if $c=\infty$ then $f(x)$ is the variance of normal variable with mean $0$ and variance $x^2$, so $f(x)=x^2$. However, for $c>0$ I couldn't see that easily. Checking the first derivative doesn't help either. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't see if it is positive

Comment: Did you try ploting this function? Maybe the graph will suggest it's rate of increasing.

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for your advice @TZakrevskiy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function cannot be nondecreasing since it is positive and has limits zero at zero and at infinity.

Comment: Thanks @Did. I think so. I'll check the condition again